# Как правильно посчитать дни?

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Скажите, пожалуйста, с какого дня мне вести отсчет дней, если было сказано такое предложение: "Сегодня идет третий день, с тех пор как это случилось"?
А случилось преступление, и было оно около 16:00 часов (т. е. время в этом дне еще остается) или все-таки начинать отсчет со следующего дня? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Предположим, что убийство случилось в понедельник, в 16:15. Во вторник, до 16:15, будет идти первый день, после 16:15 — второй день; в среду, до 16:15, будет идти второй день, после 16:15 — третий день; в четверг, до 16:15, будет идти третий день, после 16:15 — четвертый день.
Сказать: «Сегодня идет третий день, как случилось убийство.» — могут в среду, после 16:15, и в четверг, до 16:15.
Конечно же нужно начинать отчет с момента убийства.

Comment: Чётко! Плюс вам!

Comment: Благодарю за похвалу.